# Behaviour in Android Doze when using different Scheduler

Tags: android, doze

I'm trying to optimize our app for `Doze` and `AppStandBy` and have implemented a
test application to understand the behaviour of the system when using different background schedulers.

However I'm very confused about the behaviour when using `AlarmManager` and `Observable.intervall()`.

**AlarmManager**

I have registered an alarm through an `Activity` and then brought the device via adb in Doze.
The system behaves as expected, the alarm is not fired.

**Rx-Observable.intervall**

I have started a `Service` through an `Activity` and then brought the device via adb in Doze. The `Service` is **NOT** a foreground service.
The system does not behave as expected in my eyes and the ticks are continuous delivered to the app.

To veryfy that the device was really in `Doze` I also reviewed the battery statistics with `adb bugreport`, and the historian tells me that the device was in `Doze` in that timespan.

Is there any documentation how the different schedulers work in `Doze` or `AppStandBy`?

Thanks for any advice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem seems to be that `adb` keeps the CPU running (if the device is connected via usb) even if the device brought to `doze` by `adb` with the commands

`$ adb shell dumpsys battery unplug`

`$ adb shell input keyevent KEYCODE_POWER`

`adb shell dumpsys deviceidle step`

The interval timer scheduled by `ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor` (used by rxjava) seems not to be restricted in `doze` mode but alarms via `AlarmManager` do.